# Using named pipe better way

Tags: c, linux, select, pipe

I already have 3 programs,
which **get sensor data** and **send it to my remote server** by TLS each.

I wanted to diet the TLS header,
so I decided to seperate above programs to
3 * (sensor data getting program) + 1 * (tls send-only program),
using named PIPE as inter-process communication(not socket).

However now I'm wondering about which one is better to

1. use 1 named pipe with 3 writer + 1 reader

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   mkfifo /tmp/tls/pipe
   /app/sensor1 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe
   /app/sensor2 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe
   /app/sensor3 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe
   /app/tls_sender /tmp/tls/pipe
   ```
2. use 3 named pipe of each writer + use IO muliplexing like `select()` in reader?

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   mkfifo /tmp/tls/pipe1
   mkfifo /tmp/tls/pipe2
   mkfifo /tmp/tls/pipe3
   /app/sensor1 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe1
   /app/sensor2 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe2
   /app/sensor3 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe3
   /app/tls_sender /tmp/tls/pipe1 /tmp/tls/pipe2 /tmp/tls/pipe3
   ```

with tls sender like

```
#define SENSOR_NUM 3

int tls_flags[SENSOR_NUM];
char huge_buffer[HUGE_NUM];
int tls_send(int idx, char* buf) {
    // set flags for each readfds index
    // if all index counts to some threshold, send huge_buffer at once
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    int fd[SENSOR_NUM];
    int state;
    char buf[255];
    fd_set readfds;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    for(int i=0; i<SENSOR_NUM; i++)
    {
        fd[i] = open(argv[i+1], O_RDONLY);
        FD_SET(fd[i], &readfds);
    }
    while(1) {
        state = select(fd[2]+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        switch(state)
        {
            // case -1: error exception
            // case 0 : no send
            default:
                for (int i=0; i<SENSOR_NUM; i++){
                    if (FD_ISSET(fd[i], &readfds))
                        read(fd[i], buf, 255);
                        tls_send(i, buf);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I guess former would be easier to implement and faster but latter would be more stable, but I'm not sure about it.

Is former stable enough without using semaphore or something?
Or latter is faster or vulnerable?
Or even shared-memory approach without PIPE is enough?
Which one is better and recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to keep track of where the data comes from (which sensor)? Unless the sensor data output by the sensor programs contain that in their output then the first alternative will make it impossible to tell where the data comes from.

Comment: Actually each sensor application makes the data to coded&masked packet and the packet protocol has its own sensor ID! Thanks for concerning.

Comment: `/app/sensor1 & >> /tmp/tls/pipe` The `&` is usually place on the end end, like prefer `/app/sensor1 >> /tmp/tls/pipe &` so that not to confuse with `/app/sensor1 &>> /tmp/tls/pipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maximum message size on pipes that is guaranteed to be atomic, and thus not interleave the messages: `PIPE_BUF`. If your messages would be larger, you would need semaphores or some sort of synchronization for the first method. POSIX guarantees this to be at least 512 bytes. On Linux, it's 4096. See [man (7) pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

In terms of performance, I think the difference would be negligible. If you have many small writes in a very short time span, you might see a bit better performance with the first method. This would be because you would need only one userspace/kernelspace switch: on `read`. Whereas with the second, you would need `select` and `read`. However, in most circumstances I think the majority of time is spend either waiting for data, or copying it. And waiting on `read` or on `select` doesn't matter.

With shared memory you would need to deal with synchronization issues. This *may* be faster, but is complex and error prone. You could reconsider this if you are having serious performance issues.

In short, I would recommend the first approach. It's also easier to expand or reuse.

Comment: You mean, It's better to use first method with semaphore because It has less previllaged operations and easy to reuse, but the difference would be negligible right? Thanks you so much for detailed explanation.

Comment: Right. And if you can keep all individual messages smaller than `PIPE_BUF`, you would not even need semaphores.